# Run a function every day in specific time

Tags: php, wordpress, function, api, events

I have a function which has got data from the API. **I want to run this function in every day at a specific time.** I have used below code for achieving this, but the blow of run every min. I am using this code on the 5min interval for scheduled tests. My API code is, too much long. I am using just test purpose example code there.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');
add_action( 'wp', 'my_activation' );

function my_activation() {
    if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_hourly_event' )) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
    }
}

add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

function do_this_hourly() {
    // do something every hour
    $t          = time();
    $user_login = 'test-'.$t;
    $user_email = 'test-'.$t.'@yahoo.com';
    $user_pass  = '123456';

    $userdata = compact( 'user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass' );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

    // On success.
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
        echo "User created : ". $user_id;
    }else{
        echo "<h1>User already exsist</h1>";

    }
}

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_deactivation');

function my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_hourly_event');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use crontab to do it, for example 06:02 each day.

`crontab -e` then add `6   2   *   *   *   curl http://api`

Comment: If that any way to achieve this by function? And which is the best solution between `function` and `corntab -e`

Comment: function is alswys scheduled by crontab.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I have not used `crontab -e` till now.

Comment: when you execute it, it will in contab edit mode, then add that line.

Answer (score 1):

Usage in the wp_schedule_event function would look like this:

use strtotime() function so you can specify the time of day - it will use today's date with the time that you specify.

`wp_schedule_event( strtotime('16:20:00'), 'daily', 'my_daily_event' );`

**Edit**

and you have to set next schedule time after scheduled

```
if (!wp_next_scheduled('my_daily_event')) {
    $time = strtotime('today'); //returns today midnight
    $time = $time + 72000; //add an offset for the time of day you want, keeping in mind this is in GMT.
    // Ex: $time = strtotime("+1 day");
    wp_schedule_event($time, 'daily', 'my_daily_event');
}
```